# Create a column using the assign method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

| index | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 20 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 6 | 13 |
| 7 | 33 |
| 8 | 2 |

I want to create a new column which is based on column A and create groups depending on the value of column A.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1', 3],['2', 5],['3', 20],['4',8],['5',7],['6',13],['7',33],['8',2]], columns=['index', 'A'])
df['groups'] =  df['A'].apply(lambda x: 'high' if x>15 else 'medium' if 15>=x>10 else 'low')
```

How could I do the same using assign?

```
df = df\
.assign(groups = ?)
```

Comment: `pd.cut(df['A'], bins=(-np.inf, 10, 15, np.inf), labels=['low','med','high'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `assign()` method:

```
df=df.assign(groups =df['A'].apply(lambda x: 'high' if x>15 else 'medium' if 15>=x>10 else 'low'))
```

OR

```
value=df['A'].apply(lambda x: 'high' if x>15 else 'medium' if 15>=x>10 else 'low')
df=df.assign(groups=value)
```

Now if you print your `df` you will get your desired output:

```
#output

    index   A   groups
0   1       3   low
1   2       5   low
2   3       20  high
3   4       8   low
4   5       7   low
5   6       13  medium
6   7       33  high
7   8       2   low
```

**Edit:** you can also do this by:

```
result=pd.read_csv(file).assign(groups=pd.read_csv(file)['A'].apply(lambda x: 'high' if x>15 else 'medium' if 15>=x>10 else 'low'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) here for a much more efficient approach for cases with multiple conditions. `assign` is just a method to add a new column, which could also just be done with panda's indexing methods.

```
import numpy as np
df.assign(groups=np.select([df.A>15, (df.A<=15)&(df.A>10)],
         ['high','medium'], 'low'))

  index   A  groups
0     1   3     low
1     2   5     low
2     3  20    high
3     4   8     low
4     5   7     low
5     6  13  medium
6     7  33    high
7     8   2     low
```